# Android wear emulator of api 21 does not starting, keep loading

Tags: android, android-emulator, wear-os

I want to install Watch face application in Android Wear and it needs 21 api of Android Wear. I installed all needed system images,

[image]

I am able to start Wear emulator of 20 api, but i am not able to start Wear emulator of 21 api.

Is there anything missing then please let me know?

Comment: Do you get an error or why are you unable to start the emulator?